# javascript date format date time to 0

Tags: javascript

I have this date

```
Thu Feb 24 2022 15:00:00 GMT+0400 (Russia Standard Time)
```

Can I change the `15:00:00` time to `00:00:00` for example this date must be like this

```
Thu Feb 24 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0400 (Russia Standard Time)
```

Comment: can I change  **"what"** time to 00:00:00

Comment: @Mhmdrz_A 15:00:00 to 00:00:00

Comment: Please edit the question and be more specific. Perhaps you want to set time to midnight according to string's time zone (as opposed to UTC or local time zone).

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`setUTCHours()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setUTCHours) :

```js
let date = new Date("Thu Feb 24 2022 15:00:00 GMT+0400");
console.log(date);
date.setUTCHours(0,0,0,0);
console.log(date);
```

Comment: That's 00:00:00 UTC. The expected output is 00:00:00 Russia Standard Time (though it isn't entirely clear why).